# Codeigniter raspberry2

Tags: codeigniter, raspberry-pi

Добрый день, есть малинка, на ней установлен `вэб-сервер`, странички отдаёт, но в `CI` работает только метод `index` дефолтного `контроллера`, при переходе по ссылкам ошибка вида:

> The requested URL /main/login_form was not found on this server.

`mod_rewrite` включен, содержимое .htaccess привожу:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Что я делаю не так?
Если готовы помочь, дам доступ к серверу